# Convert mail merge variable to sting with quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a proprietary system that has the ability to add HTML and Javascript to create custom pages.  The system has the ability to insert user profile fields into the HTML/Javascript a mail merge like tag.  In a project I'm working on I'm using a value from one of the users fields (User_Region) to append to a URL and create a personalized link to another system for each user.

I have been able to append the URL successfully when the value is numeric (12345) but not when it is text or alphanumeric.  For example neither "Florida" nor "123456a" work.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
 <script>
(function() {
var originalURL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php";
var userRegion = {User_Region};
document.write("NewURL = " + originalURL + "?id=" + userRegion);
})();
</script>
```

In the code {User_Region} is the mail merge tag that I use to insert the variable from the user profile field.  If the region variable is numeric like 123456 it works perfectly and it will output a URl like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=123456

However if the region variable is text or alphanumeric like Florida or 123456a then the script does not work.  Document.write does not output anything.  It seems like the function either stops or breaks. I'm guessing this has to do with a data type issue, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If I hard code the variable as a string like this the function works perfectly.

```
<script>
(function() {
var originalURL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php";
var userRegion = 'Florida';
document.write("NewURL = " + originalURL + "?id=" + userRegion);
})();
</script>
```

The above code will output a correct URL like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=Florida

I have tried numerous ways to add the single-quote marks to the {User_Region} variable without success.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried encapsulating it in quotes as such:

```
var userRegion = '{User_Region}';
```

Because I guess your framework just replaces the `{User_Region}` with something else, please inform me if I got it wrong. I didn't quite get what this `tag` is. You see, in JS, curly braces are used to define Objects.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it works!  That's just embarrassing that I was trying all of these highly complicated options to string things together when all I really needed to was to just add the quotes.  Ugh!  But at least it is fixed.  Thanks again!

Comment: That's the spirit! I guess you just forgot the 3rd cup of coffee, best of luck next time! :-)